# What would connecting SWDIO and SWDCLK to a constant high or low externally do?

Tags: swd

I'm trying to understand the effect of physically connecting the SWDIO and SWDCLK pins (for a chip that only has these) to a ground or VCC plane.

Would driving them low have the chip understand it's being debugged, resulting in it freezing forever as it awaits new clock cycles that never come ?

Would driving them high externally have the chip proceed as usual, but any attempt to then connect to these and debug the chip would cause a short and most likely fry the (a) chip ?

Extra question - when the SWD pins are "high", we do mean the "GPIO high" of chips, correct ?

Thanks.

Comment: Which IC are you talking about?

Comment: My use case would be for the RP2040, though I was hoping things would be the same accross MCUs (/all STM32 chips)